# Peanut butter - store bought texture at home

Tags: peanuts

I know peanut butter and other nut butters can easily be made at home, but they all seem to have very small bits in them.  Creamy is never the true creamy smooth of big brand store bought.  Is it possible to replicate the ultra smooth creamy texture of store bought at home?  I don't like nuts in my food and even the tiniest bit of texture will put me off.

Comment: Unless you have a very powerful blender or food processor and a lot of time, your texture will probably always be a bit more grainy than store bought.

Comment: related : http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/15549/67  (see especially [Flimzy's answer](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/15792/67) for some of the issues with making a grinder)

Comment: Many "big brand" peanut butters use extra ingredients to create a smooth texture, usually added oils and emulsifiers. The very best you'd ever be able to do at home / using only peanuts is equivalent to Adam's or other "natural" peanut butters. Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 4):

Well, you could shell out for a commercial nut butter mill, if you had an extra thousand bucks lying around. But otherwise the answer is probably not. I believe that commercial peanut butter makers grind the nuts between metal plates, which gives the very fine texture. At home, you're presumably using a food processor, which can't make thick-textured pastes very fine.

Some health food stores have nut butter mills, though, so if you're looking for freshness, you can grind just before you buy.

Comment: Even the nut butter mills at grocery stores will give you a grainier consistency than, say, Skippy. It's worth trying, but you still might not like it.

Comment: Harlan, it's not so much the freshness I'm looking for but the ability to create different flavors, etc.  Even if I had an extra $1000 or so, it doesn't seem like a good buy to only use occasionally!  LOL

Comment: Anthm, I'm looking for the uber-smooth texture of Skippy or any of the other big brand names' creamy peanut butter.  Any grainy will be noticable.  :(

Answer (score 0):

Add a little coconut oil to the blender and you're peanut butter will have a more creamy texture.

Comment: Any oil will add creaminess to the texture, but none will remove the small pieces the OP says are the problem.

Comment: Nope, I do it all the time and I know any oil will work but I use coconut oil. I get a smooth texture with a average blender.